# Footnote not appearing in Document

Tags: footnotes, urls

I am using a footnotes with urls inside. This works fine for most cases, but for some reason I cannot understand, sometimes the footnotes are not generated and I do not know why.

Here is the MWE (Minimal Working Example) that I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{compactdesc}
  \item[Speedup\footnote{Am I Here?}] \hfill \\  
  A missing footnote.
\end{compactdesc}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your example is not minimal at all + the problem is not with urls : even without \url command, the footnote in the items of your compactdesc environment does not show.

Comment: Footnotes are floats and thus cannot be used inside every construction. You may need to use `\item[...\footnotemark]\footnotetext{...}`

Comment: This is hardly a _minimal_ working example! It seems clear that using `\footnote` inside `\item[?]` is the cause of your problems. I checked and the use of `\url` has nothing to do with your problem. See [footnote in item](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34703/footnote-to-an-item-in-a-description-environment) for a solution.

Comment: Well, I was told that an MNE was an example that you could simply just copy and paste to reproduce the error. If you copy and paste this code you will experience the error.

Comment: I agree with @Flame_Phoenix, the MWE is just fine. The description of the problem might be lacking a bit. See my comment above.

Comment: @Andrew: Ya, looks like I cannot use `\footnote` inside `item[0]`. Place and as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `item[]\footnote{\url{}}` instead of `item[\footnote{\url{}}]`. Basically, an item cannot have a footnote inside.

Comment: yes you can, just use the method I mentioned in my comment, using `\item[...\footnotemark] \footnotetext{Text}`, then it works just fine.