# footnotemark in description environment generates error

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, description

I am writing a manual for a product, which has additional features only on select models. I, obviously, try to use footnotes to indicate the same.

Please use this [Preamble](https://github.com/abisthecodermal/latexrepo/blob/master/Preamble)

MWE:

```
\begin{description}
    \item[] \screenshot{figure name}{figure caption}
    \item[A brilliant feature\footnotemark]\footnotetext{\label{fn:onlyCol}available on select models} It helps spawn a new civilization.
    \item[Activate brilliant feature]\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}} Activates the above mentioned brilliant feature.
\end{description}
```

Errors:

`Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition. ... A brilliant feature \footnotemark]`

`Argument of \stepcounter has an extra }. ... A brilliant feature \footnotemark]`

`Paragraph ended before \stepcounter was complete. ... A brilliant feature \footnotemark]`

Steps taken so far:

1. tried removing `\label{fn:onlyCol}`
2. tried using `\footnote{available on select models}`
3. [Answer by Lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34707/95405)
4. [Answer by Uriel CP](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54240/95405)

**Class used**: Article

**Package**: Hyperref and others.

**Compiler**: XeLaTeX

**IDE**: Texstudio

Note: The suggested **Similar Questions** do not indicate that this question is a duplicate.

**EDIT:**

This works

```
\item[Activate brilliant feature]\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}} Activates the above mentioned brilliant feature.
```

But this doesn't

```
\item[Activate brilliant feature\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}}] Activates the above mentioned brilliant feature.
```

May I ask why? or will that be another question?

Comment: I can't replicate your particular problem. Please provide a *minimal* but *complete* example of code. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). I cannot reproduce that error if I stick that block of code between `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref} \begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, though the command `\screenshot` will generate an error.

Comment: apologies. I will add the preamble too...

Comment: Link to the preamble on git added....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a case of a fragile command (`\footenotemark`) in a moving argument (`\item`). So put `\protect` before the `\footnotemark`.

```
 \item[A brilliant feature\protect\footnotemark]\footnotetext{\label{fn:onlyCol}available on select models} It helps spawn a new civilization.
```

The LaTeX book gives some information about fragile commands. At least every command that has an optional argument or a `*` form is fragile. `\footnotemark` (and `\footnote`) have an optional argument and so they are fragile. Normally the `\item` in a list is a safe place, but apparently due to your customization with `\setlist` is has become a moving place that is unsafe for fragile commands. Usually the kind of error message you get:

```
Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition
```

gives me a hunch that there are fragile commands involved.

Anyway, putting `\protect` before a command when it is not really needed is usually harmless.

Comment: Yes it did work!! Thanks! Now, how do I know which command needs `\protect` and which doesn't?

Comment: The LaTeX book gives some information about fragile commands. At least every command that has an optional argument or a `*` form is fragile. `\footnotemark` (and `\footnote`) have an optional argument and so they are fragile. Normally the `\item` in a list is a safe place, but apparently due to your customization with `\setlist` is has become a moving place that is unsafe for fragile commands. Usually the kind of error message you get ("Use of `\@xfootnotemark` doesn't match its definition") gives me a hunch that there are fragile commands involved.

Comment: Would you please move this reasoning to your answer for others to read?

Comment: Thanks. Would you please look at the details in edit segment of this question?