# \ref{} (cross-reference) within description environment

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, description

In continuation of a question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344694/footnotemark-in-description-environment-generates-error),
why is it that

This doesn't work (`\ref{}` *inside* the description)

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%                            for colors
\usepackage{enumitem}%                             Blue and bold numbers
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            urlcolor=VIARed,
            linkcolor=VIARed]{hyperref}%    Define clickable URL without boundaries around them

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%   Colour Declarations 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{VIAGray}{HTML}{575759}
\definecolor{VIARed}{HTML}{C40F39}

\setlist[description,1]{font=\color{VIAGray}\MakeUppercase}
\setlist[description,2]{font=\color{VIAGray}\MakeUppercase}
\setlist[description,3]{font=\color{VIAGray}\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\section{some section}\label{fn:onlyCol}
    \begin{description}
        \item[Activate brilliant feature\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}}] Activates the above mentioned brilliant feature.
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

May I ask why?

Do let me know if I can provide any more details.

**EDIT:**

MWE complete. Of course I also want to know 'how' to make it work. Not just the why? :P

Comment: MWE with all relevant data would be more helpful as you preamble is rather large.

Comment: apologies. The complete MWE has been posted. Stripped of everything.... The previous comment was stupid. I will remove it.

Comment: You get the warning `LaTeX Warning: Reference \`fn:onlyCol' on page 1 undefined on input line 29.` because you have a `\ref` but never set a `\label` with that value.

Comment: If I add `aaaaaa\footnote{\label{fn:onlyCol}aaaaaaa}` after `\begin{document}` the reference works as expected.

Comment: Apologies. It works because the `\ref{}` was outside the `\item[]`. I have corrected the MWE. So the problem appears now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*now* you get the error

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `FN:ONLYCOL' on page 1 undefined on input line 21.
```

The problem is that you have uppercased the reference string.

You could use `\MakeTextUppercase` from the `textcase` package that tries to step past such things or simply hide it in a macro

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}%                            for colors
\usepackage{enumitem}%                             Blue and bold numbers
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            urlcolor=VIARed,
            linkcolor=VIARed]{hyperref}%    Define clickable URL without boundaries around them

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%   Colour Declarations 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{VIAGray}{HTML}{575759}
\definecolor{VIARed}{HTML}{C40F39}

\setlist[description,1]{font=\color{VIAGray}\MakeUppercase}
\setlist[description,2]{font=\color{VIAGray}\MakeUppercase}
\setlist[description,3]{font=\color{VIAGray}\MakeUppercase}

% would need \protect\foo when used
%\newcommand\foo{\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}}}

%LaTeX protect mechanism
%\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}}}

%etex pfrotection mechanism
\protected\def\foo{\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}}}

\begin{document}
\section{some section}\label{fn:onlyCol}
    \begin{description}
        \item[Activate brilliant feature\foo] Activates the above mentioned brilliant feature.
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Let me try it out once please.

Comment: Can a command be protected when its declared? I mean here...

`\newcommand\foo{\textsuperscript{\ref{fn:onlyCol}}}`. Because the value `fn:onlyCol` will vary...

Comment: @manucpp done..

Comment: Also, if I have to declare a command, can we get it to accept arguments? Like `\protected\def\foo#1{\textsuperscript{\ref{#1}}}`?